# Configuring and implement Soap STS instance in OpenAM?

Tags: security, web, soap, openam

I am new to implementing Soap STS in OpenAM, I am not knowing what flow to follow. Please help me how to implement the Soap STS please tell some steps or flow to follow to do this task .

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: i want a flow or steps to configure the soap sts in openam